# How to configure Vim's indentation for closing braces in C and C++ files?

Tags: c++, vim

I'm working with some code (C and C++) that's presently formatted as (3 spaces):

```
void foo() {
   bar();
   }
```

I want to modify the code so that it's indented one more space (4 spaces):

```
void foo() {
    bar();
    }
```

In Vim I've set:

```
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
```

But then when I use == or ='(mark) to autoindent a line or set of lines, it gives me:

```
void foo() {
    bar();
}
```

Is there a setting which controls how the closing brace is indented? The practice for the code I'm working on presently is that the closing brace is indented the same amount as the contents of the block. Vim, however, does not indent the closing brace.

Comment: I have _never_ seen that practice, and it hurts my eyes. Showing scope with the indentation level is great.

Comment: That's _really_ weird. Why do you want to do that? Everyone in the world will complain about your code.

Comment: I'll agree it's weird, but changing it is a non-option as this point. It's got to match some other code that was written similarly. I'm working on one component of a multi-component project, and that's the scheme that's been used.

I actually quite like it after having dealt with it for a while. I find it to be quicker to identify closing brackets when there are lots of short, nested blocks.

Comment: Wikipedia [claims there's precedent for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Banner_style), but I'm not 100% convinced.  Not like it *matters*, of course.

Comment: @Kevin How about that :p And, python does have that same "visual scanning" thing going for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you're using the [`cindent` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27cindent%27).  Then you can just set `cino=}1s` to indent the closing braces by one level of indentation (one `shiftwidth`).  See [cinoptions-values](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values) in vim help for more information.

Comment: That does the trick. I'm not sure how I managed to miss those options in the docs, but apparently I did. Thanks!